# How to get browsers to release memory used by OfflineAudioContext?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm using [OfflineAudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext) to render WebAudio signals into a buffer so I can analyze the results. When I do this repeatedly, it seems that the associated memory is never released, eventually causing the browser tab to crash.

Here's a minimal reproduction:

```
// render 10 minutes of audio into a big buffer
var ctx = new OfflineAudioContext(1, 44100 * 600, 44100)
var osc = ctx.createOscillator()
osc.start()
ctx.startRendering().then(buffer => {
    // attempt to clean up
    osc.stop()
    osc = null
    buffer = null
    ctx = null
})
```

Running that in a JS console will render a ~100MB buffer that never gets released. Running it repeatedly will chew up memory until the tab eventually crashes (tested in mac chrome/mozilla, windows chrome/mozilla/edge).

How can I get browsers to free the memory associated with an `OfflineAudioContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [confirmed as a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=894322#c8), with no workarounds. Until it's fixed, it looks like this is a fact of life.

Answer (score 0):

This one was a major headache, but I finally found a workaround: create an `iframe` in which you run the audio rendering code, return the result to your main window using `postMessage`, and immediately remove the `iframe` from the DOM when you receive the result. That clears all resources associated with it, including the `offlineAudioContext`.

Of course, that's only practical if your use case is to do a relatively small number of relatively long renders.

Note that to transfer the data back in an efficient manner, you should send `ArrayBuffer` objects, which are `Transferable`:

```
context.oncomplete = function (e) {
  var channels = [];
  for (var c = 0; c < e.renderedBuffer.numberOfChannels; c++) {
    channels.push(e.renderedBuffer.getChannelData(c));
  }
  channels = channels.map( function(c) {return c.buffer;} );
  window.parent.postMessage({
    action:'renderResult',
    data: channels
  }, "*", channels);
}
```

and recreate Float32Arrays from them on the receiving end.